# JQuery CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am having trouble getting this animation to work.

```
$("#selectedTime").stop().animate({
    "margin-left": "-=470px"
},"fast", function() {
    $(this).css({ "margin-left": "620px"
})}).animate({
    "margin-left": "-=470px"
},"fast");
```

I am sliding the div to the left 470px, jumping to 620px and sliding another 470px to the left. $(this).css({ "marginLeft": "620px" does not seem to be working.

The initial margin-left is 150px. After running the script it is -790px. (150-470-470).

Comment: And what's the trouble you're having?

Comment: -=, did u try with simply -470px?

Comment: What other CSS is applied to `#selectedTime`?

Answer (score 1):

To start, you've got syntax errors:

```
$("#selectedTime").stop().animate({
    "margin-left": "-=470px"
},"fast", function() {              // ↓↓↓ here 
    $(this).css({ "margin-left": "620px"}); 
}).animate({
    "margin-left": "-=470px"
},"fast");
```

---

```
$("#selectedTime")
    .stop()
    .animate({"margin-left": "-=470px"}, "fast")
    .animate({"margin-left": "620px"}, 0)
    .animate({"margin-left": "-=470px"}, "fast");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/j7rcr/

Comment: Same problem. Still ending up at -790px.

Comment: Beautiful. I guess it makes sense that it should be an animation, I didn't think of setting the duration to 0 though. Thank you!!